# How do I connect to Weblogic JMS from Websphere server?

Tags: java, interop, jms, weblogic, websphere

I created a small standalone client using:

```
weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
t3://weblogic-server:7001

jms.xyz.jmsXyzCf
jms/xyz/jmsXyzLogQueue
```

And it works flawlessly.

When a try to run the same code from my websphere server I get `NullPointerException`. I understand this happens because I don't have weblogic classes in the classpath:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:235)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.initializeDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:327)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:357)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.internalInit(InitialContext.java:295)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.(InitialContext.java:212)
```

When I try to add them I get some "Security" errors

```
Current Java 2 Security policy reported a potential violation of Java 2 Security Permission. 

java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission exitVM.0)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:108)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:533)
at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:211)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkExit(SecurityManager.java:745)
at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:100)
at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:297)
```

As last resource, I tried to connect using websphere own context factory: `com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory` but of course it fails because it doesn't understand t3.

**Question**

How can I connect to a weblogic JMS from Websphere?

Comment: The reason you get a Security Permission error is because something is trying to invoke a System.exit. Look at the stack trace. exitVM: This target grants permission to halt the Java VM. Granting this permission could allow malicious code to mount a denial-of-service attack by automatically forcing the VM to stop.

Comment: I don't see how that (System.exit) is triggered from the stack trace you have posted here. It makes good sense to me that the J2 Security Policy is preventing access asotherwise your run-time WAS server would be shut down which you would certainly not be interested in. Is there any other stuff in the logs (this exit might be related to something else, another app hosted on the same server as an example,.

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere isn't exactly known for its friendliness towards running system-level functionality (such as JNDI) using third party implementations. You will have to, at the end, use WebSphere's classes (including WebSphere's InitialContextFactory implementation).

When running under WebSphere, you don't need (and actually, *shouldn't*) explicitly specify the InitialContextFactory implementation; WebSphere can (and should) conclude it itself.

If I understand correctly, you're trying to connect to WebLogic JMS Administered Objects from within a WebSphere server process. The only way I can think of, to do that, would be to obtain WebLogic JMS's implementation classes and adding it as a JMS provider, then use JNDI to look it up. I'll be happy to stand corrected, though.